# Is it possible to levitate large objects through diamagnetic levitation?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, equilibrium, metals, levitation

I am currently building a diamagnetic levitator with a strong neodymium magnet, two slabs of bismuth (a diamagnetic material), and a small neodymium cube to levitate. However, I was wondering if it would be possible to levitate a larger subject like a piece of metal the size of an iphone. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

This is the type of diamagnetic levitator I am referring to:

[image]

(Pyloric Graphite is a diamagnetic material)

Comment: Can you maybe post a link how this works (the geometry etc), is there an explanation on the internet? Also: why should it not be possible to make it bigger, did you try? Or are you asking where to get bigger magnets? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course *in theory* nothing stops you from doing the same thing on a bigger scale. Consider however that the effect is rather feeble and you need really strong field for heavier objects, which is expensive and quite cumbersome. The relevant equation is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation#Diamagnetism).

If you are mainly looking for a fascinating project, I would consider magnetic levitation, either stabilized using feedback or by having revolving magnets or some such. The version using feedback requires a bit of electronics knowledge but I have heard it is both interesting and doable.